# biblatex: track n-order crossrefs with mincrossrefs?

Tags: biblatex

I would like to automatically increment the `xref` counter of a given entry every time the `xref` counter of any of its children is incremented (*not* every time any descendant entry is cited).

Presently, the following code yields only bibliography entries for `child1` and `child2`. I would like for `grandparent` (but not `parent1` or `parent2`) to also appear in the bibliography.

```
\begin{filecontents}[force]{sx-biblatex-test.bib}
  @mvcollection{grandparent,
    editor = {Grandparent Editor},
  }

  @collection{parent1,
    crossref = {grandparent},
    editor = {Parent One},
  }

  @collection{parent2,
    crossref = {grandparent},
    editor = {Parent Two},
  }

  @incollection{child1,
    crossref = {parent1},
    author = {Child One},
  }

  @incollection{child2,
    crossref = {parent2},
    author = {Child Two}, 
  }

  @incollection{child3,
    crossref = {parent2},
    author = {Child Three},
  }
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=authoryear,mincrossrefs=2]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{sx-biblatex-test.bib}

\begin{document}
  \nocite{child1,child2}
  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

I can get the output I want in this case by adding `xref = {grandparent},` to each child entry. Adding the following code to the preamble doesn't seem to accomplish the same effect.

```
\DeclareDataInheritance{*}{*}{%
  \inherit{crossref}{xref}
}
```

Besides, this approach has the undesirable effect of adding `grandparent` to the bibliography when I only cite `child2` and `child3`.

I get the impression that the relevant macros are in `blx-bibtex.def` lines 272-324 but it's not clear to me how they work.

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: You have mentioned `xref` but are using `crossref` in the entries - these are two different mechanisms. The `\DeclareDataInheritance` system only applies to `crossref` as `xref` doesn't do data inheritance. Could you clarify?

Comment: @PLK I am using `crossref` to inherit data from a custom type `@serial` to `@periodical` and then to `@article`. When I use the `mincrossrefs=n` option, I would like an entry to be automatically added if I cite more than `n` entries that *indirectly* inherit from that entry, not just directly. I noticed that `crossref`s and `xref`s both count for the purposes of `mincrossrefs`. I tried to exploit that by passing the entry key of the grandparent entry via inheritance from the `crossref` field of the parent to the `xref` field of the child, but that didn't work.

Comment: Do the grandparent entries really constitute full, citable entries? If not, you may want to consider the XDATA interface instead.